# What to use for creating a buzzer webapp that runs on apache2

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

**What I want:**

I want to create a Buzzer System on a Website.
Every "player" can Access this site with an username an there is a Buzzer button.

I want to have somekind of adminpanel where I can see where pushed the button first and lock the Buzzer button etc. This should be near realtime if this is possible.
Maybe on the Buzzer site there is a TextBox where I can set a text for everyone.

This site should be able to run on a apache2 Server on Debian.
If I need to run some other Service ist fine too.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to make something like that with a website?
If yes, what can I use for this? (I just know how to build a website with html/JavaScript/jquery and bootstrap and I would guess I need something more to do that).

Do I need to make a .php site or maybe something with node.js?

(I dont need a full solution, just something to beginn with, but if something like this already exits with a template, I will look into this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a realtime system regardless of how complex it is, then you need  a backend (unless you want to do a p2p system, and i doubt that this is what you want, since these are not really supported on the browser - but you can look at webRTC if you are interested in this approach). Your backend can be on anything php, nodejs, or any other technology of your choice.

The old school of doing realtime over http was using http polling (long and short), currently you can use the almost new websockets which perform much more better than polling.

I would suggest that you look into socket.io, a library that makes it really easy to build real time systems on nodejs - and it falls back to http polling when websockets are not supported.

You can also search google, you will find templates of some things that looks really close to what you want to achieve, or at least look at something close, so you can learn how they did it.

Comment: So first: learn how to run a node.js website, then how to use socket.io to make a buzzer? Sound possible for me.

Comment: @sirzento yea, running a websocket server on nodejs is really easy - in fact even a webserver on nodejs is also really easy with expressJS, this is why i have recommended socketio for you ( you will still be using expressJS with socket.io) . Eventually, anything is possible if you go for it, and dedicate some time to do it.